# Is there any way to read data from HashSet as spark structured streaming using readStream() method?

Tags: apache-spark, hashmap

Reading data from HashMap using readStream() method of Spark Structured streaming method.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't

At the very least, you need to parallelize the map, but that then becomes an RDD or Dataframe if you apply a schema.

A stream in Spark (and similar frameworks) is that its an unbounded quantity of data. At any moment of a Hashmap or Hashset's existence, it has a fixed `size()`, therefore is not a stream